# Post JS Object Array to Spring MVC controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring-mvc

I am trying to pass long array from jquery load to spring controller. How can i sent js object array t spring mvc controller.

Every time action occured the no data alert on script will called.
**Script**

```
var arr = [];//Array
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".rating").click(function() {
            var idx = $(this).closest('td').index();

            var userskill = {//Object
                tech : $(this).closest('td').siblings('td.tech').text(),
                skill : $('#listTable thead th').eq(idx).text(),
                rValue : $(this).val()

            }
            add(userskill);
        });

    });


function add(userskill) {
    arr.push(userskill);
    $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        dataType : 'json',
        url : '/SimplWebApp/saveUserRating',
        data : ({
            id : JSON.stringify(arr)
        }),
        success : function(responseData) {
            if (responseData != null) {

                alert(responseData);
            } else {
                alert("no data");
            }
        }

    });

}
```

**controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "saveUserRating")
public @ResponseBody String saveUserRating(@RequestParam(value="id[]", required=false) String[] x) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String data = gson.toJson(x);

    return data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The JSON array resides in the body of the request. You can use the `@RequestBody` annotation to obtain the array if you have Jackson on the classpath to deserialize the JSON.

```
saveUserRating(@RequestBody(required=false) String[] ids)
```

If you want to use the array as the response body simply return the array from the handler method. It will be serialized to JSON automatically.

```
@ResponseBody
public String[] saveUserRating(saveUserRating(@RequestBody(required=false) String[] ids)) {
    return ids;
}
```